# spares missing on ubuntu mdadm software raid 5 how to disable?

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

I want to understand and if it makes sense, disable the alert message I receive about spares missing on my ubuntu linux software raid 5.

I used mdadm and set up a /dev/md0 raid volume made up of 3 hard drives.

I then set up email alerts so I can see when there is a problem with it.

I often get these 'spare missing' alerts, and I assume that means there is a second spare defined and I do not have one.

I am looking to clarify that this is actually not really a problem, and that I can change a setting to tell mdadm I do not have a second spare (I have only 3 drives).   My system should continue running if 1 drive goes down?

Here is the alert message:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm running on myserver

A SparesMissing event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] md0 : active raid5 sdc1[1] sdb1[0] sdd1[2]
      1953519488 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: How is the group defined in `mdadm.conf`?

Comment: DEVICE partitions
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 spares=1 UUID=80c8bec2:d8660d29:ae8962f                                 2:b7b9c495   , so I assume spares=0 would fix it, but is there a negative to this?  A spare is optional, correct?  Raid 5 means if 1 drive goes down the other 2 will keep running, correct?

Comment: So is it safe to set it to spares=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set to 0 spares; a RAID 5 group will be able to tolerate 1 failure of an active disk.  A spare is used as a reserved disk to immediately start rebuilding the array if one of the active disks dies.